# Postgres + Select query from Cache

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering if Postgres had a feature like SQL_CACHE in mySQL.  For example in mySQL I can do a query like  "SELECT SQL_CACHE Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Sku FROM Products" I want to know if I can do something similar in Postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL automatically caches recently accessed data in memory, depending on your `shared_buffers` configuration parameter. There's really no need for an `SQL_CACHE` feature, since Postgres already does a great job of managing the tuple cache.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. `effective_cache_size` does not influence the cache that Postgre manages. It only give the planner a hint how like it will be that data is already in the filesystem cache. The bigger that value, the less expensive random seeks are treated.

Comment: Wrong parameter, the only cache PostgreSQL has, is shared_buffers.

Comment: @Frank. That's what I get for typing too quickly. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

In `MySQL`, `SQL_CACHE` doesn **not** select from cache, depending on `query_cache_type`, this happens:

- *1 or ON*: Cache all cacheable query results except for those that begin with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`.
- *2 or DEMAND*: Cache results only for cacheable queries that begin with `SELECT SQL_CACHE`.

In essence, using `SQL_NO_CACHE` with any setting other the `1` or `SQL_CACHE` with any other setting the `2` is *meaningless*.

If this is still what you need in PostgreSQL: no idea, but I had to make this very clear.

Answer (score 0):

just simple goto /etc/postgresql/YOUREVERSION/main/posgresql.conf (*nix) (
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\YOUREVERSION\data\postgresql.conf (win))
find shared_buffers, uncomment itб and specify need cache size.